# getting 500 error on laravel and vuejs inserting to database + logfile

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to store data into my database using **VueJs** and I keep receiving 500 error
here is my **code**:

```
export default {
    props: ['post_id','user_id'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            body:'',
            user_name : '',
        }
    },
```

and the **methods** is here:

```
methods: {
    loadComments() {
        // axios.get("../api/comment").then(({ data })=>(this.comments - data.data)
        axios.get("../api/comment").then((response) => (this.comments = response.data.data)
            // response => this.comments = response.data
        );
    },
    create() {
        axios.post('../api/comment',{body:this.body});
    },
```

and here is a part of my **form**:

```
<form @submit.prevent="create()"  id="myForm"  class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right m-form--group-seperator-dashed">
    <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="insert name" name="body" class="form-control m-input" v-model="body">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>email</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="title" class="form-control m-input">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the **route** for api laravel:

```
Route::resource('comment','CommentController');
```

and finally here is what I get as **log error** in laravel :

> [2019-03-25 07:07:08] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'body' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `comments` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-03-25 07:07:08, 2019-03-25 07:07:08)) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'body' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `comments` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-03-25 07:07:08, 2019-03-25 07:07:08)) at C:\wamp\www\jabama3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'body' doesn't have a default value at C:\wamp\www\jabama3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458)

i know that my form is not sending data and laravel needs the data but i dont know which part i am doing wrong .

Edit here is my store method :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    Comment::create($request->all());
    return (['message' => 'succes']);
}
```

and here is my table structure :

```
 Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->longText('body');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('user_email')->nullable();
        $table->string('user_name');
        $table->integer('status')->default('0');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: can you share your "comments" table structure

Comment: Please can you show the `store` method for your `CommentController`.

Comment: Did you add your `body` attirbute as fillable in the `Comment` model?

Comment: @GauravGupta check i edited the question

Comment: @RossWilson check i edited answer

Comment: @namelivia yes i addes that to the model

Comment: Please can you add the `Comment` model to your as well?

Comment: as much i can see your main error is this "  Field 'body' doesn't have a default value  " in your comment table body filed don't have any default value just change it make it nullable or anything else as per your requirement

Comment: @RossWilson class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'body','user_id','user_email','user_name','status','post_id'];
}

Comment: @GauravGupta i did that but when i make body nullable it goes the same error but for next colomn which is user_id i dont know why my form is not sending data

Comment: your form only send 2 filed's

Comment: it doesnt even send the first input which in this case is body if it sends body i add the others later on

Comment: do one thing dd(Input::all()); in store function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your body is empty when you inserting data to your table.
The reason is you are using Create a method for inserting data.
And Create method needs `protected $fillable = ['field1','field2',...]` array which have your table fields in your model.
Add $fillable to your model.
You can follow this link for more information relating to [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

You create file `Comments.php` Model, you can update file `Comments.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Comments extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'body', 
        'user_id', 
        'user_email',
        'user_name',
        'status',
        'post_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

}
```

[Example Laravel + Vuejs Send Mail](http://hoanguyenit.com/send-mail-using-laravel-5-4-vuejs.html)